# Return names in a column based off value in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've looked at other suggestions, but I can't find one that matches what I'd like to do.  I have a sheet with names across the top and names down the left side.  I want to return a list of names across the top that match a name on the left where an X (or a specific text string) is in the cell under the name across the top:

```
            | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 | Name 4 | Name 5 |
----------------------------------------------------------
Employee 1  |        |    X   |        |    X   |        |
----------------------------------------------------------
Employee 2  |    X   |        |        |        |    X   |
----------------------------------------------------------
Employee 3  |        |        |   X    |        |        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to get a return like:

```
Employee 1: Name 2, Name 4
Employee 2: Name 1, Name 5
Employee 3: Name 3
```

But if it's one return per employee line that'd work also.

Comment: Hello, what did you try? There are definitely a bunch of very similar findable formulas.

Comment: I can't see any way to do this with just excel functions. I think this will require a VBA macro.

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel supports Filter and Textjoin function, please try following function.

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($B$1:$F$1,B2:F2="X"))`

[image]